# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'. How to fix this?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I'm trying to download a table as a CSV file, but I keep getting a 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import csv
import os

html1t = open("SOUP1.TABLE.ZKILL.HTML").read()
soup1t = BS(html1t)
table1 = soup1t.find('table')

output_rows = []
for table_row in table1.findAll('tr'):
    columns = table_row.find('td')
    output_row = []
    for column in columns:
        output_row.append(column.text)
    output_rows.append(output_row)

with open('./zkillboard1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(output_rows)
```

Comment: try to print `table1`, Error says this is None.

Comment: Please share the input as well

Comment: what's the url? The reason you are getting the error is because youre not getting anything with your `.find('table')`. I'm thinking you can do 1 of a few things here. 1) the page you're trying to aquire this table is dynamic and the table is rendered by javascript, whcih means you'll have to use Selenium, or access an API if available, or the table is within some `<script>` tags. 2) if you're trying to download a csv, it is possible there is a directly link to the csv. But either of these would require for me to see the site and see what's there.